# python-docx Change header left margin only

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I am using `python-docx` library to add an image to header and footer of a `.docx` file.

By default, there is a left margin to both Header-Footer as well as the Page.

In order to change the left margin of Header-Footer to 0 if I use `section.left_margin = 0` this sets the margin of whole page to 0. But I only want to change the left margin of Header-Footer to 0.

So: How can I change the left margin of only the Header and Footer using `python-docx` or any other library.

Current Document Image - if I simply add Image to header and footer that has same width as `section`'s width:

[image]

Document Image if I also do `section.left_margin = 0`:

[image]

What I actually want:

[image]

Comment: Actually, if you look at the Word UI you'll see that it's *not* possible to change the left-/right-margins for just the header or footer. These margins are for the entire page. The top and bottom margins can be adjusted independently, which may be the reason for the confusion.

Comment: What you *can* do, however, is change the **indent** of the paragraph formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Cindy mentions in her comment: You can't change header margins, because page margins are an attribute of the *section* and therefore apply to both headers and the body. What you *can* do is change paragraph indents, and there are at least two approaches here.

1. Change left indent to a negative value:

   ```
   from docx.shared import Inches

   header = section.header
   paragraph = header.paragraphs[0]
   paragraph.paragraph_format.left_indent = -Inches(1.0)
   ```
2. Change right indent such that `right_indent + right_margin = left_margin`:

   ```
   paragraph.paragraph_format.right_indent = Inches(0.5)
   ```

Note that this indentation must be applied to all paragraphs in the header you want aligned this way; indentation is paragraph-by-paragraph.